# Is there really no way to update VS Code when building it from source?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does this issue occur when all extensions are disabled?: Yes

VS Code Version: 1.84.0
OS Version: Windows 11

Steps to Reproduce:

build vscode source code using yarn and.\scripts\code.bat
the main window shows but no way to update

I want to modify the upgrade-related code in the VSCode source code, mostly in `updateService.win32`. However, after compiling the source code, I didn't find buttons like 'check for updates,' and I noticed that `CONTEXT_UPDATE_STATE` is set to `StateType.Disabled` Can anyone give me some suggestions on debugging after modifying the upgrade code?

Comment: I'm confused what you expect ect to happen. If you're building it from source then the first time it updates it would replace your build with the official build. I which case, what was the point of building it yourself? If you had a point in building it yourself then to keep that point you'd need to upgrade yourself by syncing the latest source, merging your changes, and rebuilding

Comment: @gman "_I want to modify the upgrade-related code in the VSCode source code_"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer to this question is "It just be like that". There are a number of reasons why updates can be disabled, which you can find by [searching for the string `setState(State.Disabled` in the VS Code codebase](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Amicrosoft%2Fvscode%20%22setState(State.Disabled%22&type=code). But the reason I think is of primary interest here is the one that goes like this:

> ```js
> if (!this.environmentMainService.isBuilt) {
>   this.setState(State.Disabled(DisablementReason.NotBuilt));
>   return; // updates are never enabled when running out of sources
> }
> ```

At the time of this writing, [for desktop VS Code, `isBuilt`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/860d67064a9c1ef8ce0c8de35a78bea01033f76c/src/vs/platform/environment/common/environmentService.ts#L210) returns `!env['VSCODE_DEV']`, and [for web VS Code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/860d67064a9c1ef8ce0c8de35a78bea01033f76c/src/vs/workbench/services/environment/browser/environmentService.ts#L55), `!!this.productService.commit`. Maybe you could try invoking your VS Code with `VSCODE_DEV` defined in its environment.

Other reasons updates can be disabled include

- disabling by environment by passing `--disable-updates` when invoking VS Code from commandline.
- there not being an `updateUrl` set in the `product.json` file used for the build. (there's a template `product.json` file [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/product.json). VS Code uses `https://update.code.visualstudio.com`)
- the user disabling it via the `update.mode` setting.
- malformed update URL.
- running a Windows User Install of VS Code as Admin (pretty sure this not relevant here by virtue of being related to installations).

Obviously, you can just comment out the code that does those things, but I have no idea whether that would work (especially the one about `isBuilt`). Presumably it's there for a reason.

Comment: It works fine after commenting out those codes. Thank you very much!!!